# Rails Search with multiple Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am trying to search for results with the following conditions

> Hosts has_many events
>
> hosts(id, name, host_type, ....)
>
> events(id, name, host_id, ....)

1. Default Showing all Events results
2. Showing results based on the `query` on Events
3. Based on if `host_type` has been chosen based on related Model `Hosts`

Right now i am doing an `if else` statement but as the options grows it will become too many conditional code.

```
if params[:query].blank?
      @events_results = Event.order('event_date ASC').all
    else
      @events_results = Event.where("name LIKE '%#{params[:query]}%'").order('event_date ASC').all
    end
```

**EDIT**

Based on some research and the answers i have modified to the following

```
  def index

    @events_results ||= find_events

  end

  private

  def find_events
    events = Event.order('event_date ASC').all
    events = events.where("name LIKE '%#{params[:query]}%'") if params[:query].present?
    events = events.includes(:host).where("Host.host_type = ?", params[:host_type]) if params[:query].present?
    events
  end
```

**Error:**

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'Host.host_type' in 'where clause':
>   SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (name LIKE '%menu%') AND
>   (Host.host_type = '1') ORDER BY event_date ASC

Comment: make it `hosts.host_type`, as there is always the table name in the raw sql part. And `hosts` should be your table name and `host_type` its column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create an initial query and chain on it while you go, from what I can see the `order` part is common and always present, so use it as the base query

```
@event_results = Event.order(event_date: :asc)
@event_results = @event_results.where('event_results.name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%") if params[:query]
@event_results = @event_results.joins(:host).where(host_type: params[:host_type]) if proper_condition
@event_results = @event_results.more_methods if more_conditions
#etc

@event_results #the return
```

By default ruby will return the last statement, so you don't need to use `return`, unless the last statement returns something like `true/false` then you should just add a new line with the variable `@event_results`

> **NOTE**: never use input directly from params into your query, you're allowing people to inject sql to your code, use the substitution
>   method so that `ActiveRecord` would sanitize the input for you.
>
> **Bad:**
>
> ```
> where("name LIKE '%#{params[:query]}%'")
> ```
>
> **Good:**
>
> ```
> where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%")
> ```

Comment: thanks you. i think i have used something similar as u suggested. But looks like i am not able to do the search based on the related model with this method. have updated my question.

Comment: you need to use `joins` not `includes`, i've added that condition to my answer

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` INNER JOIN `hosts` ON `hosts`.`id` = `events`.`host_id` WHERE (name LIKE '%menu%') AND (Host.host_type = '1') ORDER BY event_date ASC

Comment: then you need to be more specific, `event_results.name like ..` will update my answer

Comment: when you pass a string to `where` it's passed to the db, so you can't use the class format, you need to use the actual table name, you could use the class if you want but it would be more complicated for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if params[:query].present?

```
@events_results = Event.order('event_date ASC').all

@events_results = Event.where("name LIKE '%#{params[:query]}%'").order('event_date ASC').all if params[:query].present?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can guard clause over conditionals:

```
def events_results
  return Event.order('event_date ASC').all if params[:query].blank?
  return Event.where("name LIKE '%#{params[:query]}%'").order('event_date ASC').all if host_type
  return something_else if_some_other_codn_met
end
```

This way you don't need to bother with `if else`/`case` statements and it looks cleaner (imo).

Comment: you have a double `if` in the first `return`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a conditional string first like this:

```
conditions = ""
if params[:query].present?
  conditions += " name LIKE '%#{params[:query]}%'"
elsif params[:anything].present?
  conditions += " query" #if you have OR condtion either the first parameter or this one
end
if params[:something_else].present?
  conditions += " AND query"
end
@events_results = Event.where(conditions).order('event_date ASC').all
```

And also I will recommend to use something like `elasticsearch` or `solr` for this type of tasks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the problem of having to create different searches based on query params as well and created a little gem to help me.

https://github.com/fortytools/forty_facets

Answer (score 1):

In your edit should your second check for params[:query].present? be for params[:host_type]?

Also in the case where you have a query string you are making a call to .all first then immediately filtering on a LIKE so you should consider refactoring this as it will be a performance issue because you wouldn't have needed to make the call to .all and it will result in an additional query.

Comment: yeah changed that to `host_type` when some one visits the Search page from the link Events i wanna display all the events thats why i was doing `.all`